# Was the famous “Wilhelm Scream” used in “The Last Jedi?”

Tags: star-wars, sound-effects, the-last-jedi

Did the famous Wilhelm Scream, used in all the previous Star Wars films, appear in The Last Jedi?

Comment: I can't extend it past a few lines, but no, in neither of my two viewings did I see it, neither did the people at the [wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wilhelm_scream)

Comment: I did check out that page. It didn't say there isn't a scream, so I couldn't rule out that it hadn't been updated yet. This might be just obscure enough of a topic that it wasn't immediate updated in said wiki at 00:02:34:01 when the first fan walked out of the first midnight showing.

Comment: See - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177258/was-there-a-wilhelm-scream-in-the-last-jedi

Answer (score 12):

I was able to attend a screening of the movie today at Skywalker ranch. After the movie I spoke with the sound designer ([Ren Klyce](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0460274/?ref_=nv_sr_1)) and the sound supervisor ([Matthew Wood](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0003214/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1)) and asked them specifically about this as I swore that Kylo's lightsaber was an altered Wilhelm. They said they did not use the Wilhelm in The Last Jedi or Rogue One. They hinted that they have been using a new sound in a similar fashion for the last few movies they worked on but didn't want to point it out just yet. I thought it was a nice little teaser for the future.

[Here is the interview](http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/famous-wilhelm-scream-silent-star-wars-galaxy/story?id=52911832).

Comment: Do you have any kind of source for this?  Do you have any way to corroborate this?  How were you able to get an invite for a screening at Skywalker ranch?  Did you win some kind of contest or do you know George Lucas personally?

Comment: I have been fortunate enough to be invited there a couple times now, the source was myself and a conversation I had with Matthew Wood and Ren Klyce after the movie. I asked them specifically about the scene in questions as it sounded close but not quite. And they told me they did not use that sound in The Last Jedi or Rogue one. They did mention a different sound they have been using but would not elaborate. I am betting it sounds pretty darn close and that may be most of their inside joke is they have everyone talking about how the Wilhelm was in Last Jedi and Rogue but in reality it was not.

Answer (score 4):

Matthew Woods who did the audio for the last jedi [confirmed there was no Whilem Scream](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2314702/star-wars-the-last-jedis-sound-designer-explains-moving-on-from-the-wilhelm-scream) in *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*:

> The film did not include a single instance of the famous Wilhelm Scream. Mathew Wood, the supervising sound editor on The Last Jedi, recently revealed that Skywalker Sound has decided to "move on." According to Wood...
>
> "In this movie, we decided to move from the Wilhelm scream. We're letting the past die, as Kylo Ren says."

Answer (score 1):

I was searching the internet because I could have sworn I heard the WIlhelm Scream in a swooping motion of Kylo Rens light-saber during one of the scenes. I haven't found anyone else say they noticed it, though I am all but certain it was there.

EDIT: It appears I was right. In front of the mine doors immediately after Luke ducks Kylo Rens first attack.

Comment: I believe it was in his confrontation with Luke in front of the mine doors, specifically after Luke had ducked a slash of the lightsaber.

Comment: It is indeed, I knew id heard it. Its immediately after he ducks Kylo Rens first attack (not the matrix move). Definitely sounds like the Wilhelm scream to me.

Comment: Apparently confirmed  - http://www.gamesradar.com/star-wars-the-last-jedi-easter-eggs/